# How to create an environment variable that is the output of a command

Tags: environment-variables, alias

How do I create an environment variable that is the result of a specific command? 
Specifically, I want an environment variable ($BWD) that is the basename of $PWD

```
$ cd /home/devel/Autils/lib
$ echo $PWD
/home/devel/Autils/lib
$ # something here to assign BWD
$ echo $BWD
lib
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In general the sequence `foo="$(bar)"` will run the command `bar` and assign the output to the variable.

e.g.

```
% echo $PWD
/home/sweh
% BWD="$(basename "$PWD")"
% echo $BWD
sweh
```

This creates a shell variable.  If you want to make it into an *environment* variable (which can be seen by sub-shells) you can `export` it.

e.g.

```
export BWD="$(basename "$PWD")"
```

However, in this case don't need to *run* a command, but use shell variable expansion

```
BWD=${PWD##*/}
```

Comment: The next step would be to automatically update `BWD` when `cd` is used: `cd () { builtin cd "$@" && BWD=${PWD##*/}; }`.

Comment: @Kusalananda  `trap 'BWD=${PWD##*/}' DEBUG` :-)

Comment: Depending on the shell used, yes.

Comment: I'd add quotes to the `echo` commands as well.

Answer (score 17):

In Bourne-like shells, you create *environment* variables by marking a *shell* variable with the `export` attribute (so it's exported to the environment of the commands that the shell will execute) by using the `export` builtin utility:

```
export BWD
```

To assign a value to a shell variable, the syntax is:

```
BWD=value
```

You can make that value the output of command by using *command substitution*. In the Bourne shell, that was with the `` `the-command` `` syntax, but in modern Bourne-like shells, the preferred way is with `$(the-command)` instead:

```
BWD=$(the-command)
```

Usually, you need quotes around command substitutions to prevent *split+glob*. However, split+glob doesn't occur in assignments to scalar variables, so they're not necessary here.

The command to get the base name of a file path is the `basename` command.

```
basename "$PWD"
```

(the quotes there are necessary as split+glob does occur in arguments to commands).

That would return the base name of the file stored in `$PWD`, unless that value starts with `-`, in which case, YMMV as many `basename` implementations will treat it as an option. So generally, when passing  variable data to command, we use a `--` to tell the command that what's after is not to be taken as an option even if it starts with `-` (here, `$PWD` should always start with `/` except in very pathological cases, so it's not strictly needed).

```
BWD=$(basename -- "$PWD")
export BWD
```

In modern shells, you can combine both with:

```
export BWD="$(basename -- "$PWD")"
```

(the quotes are needed in some implementations as we're back in the arguments of commands, though some other implementations do parse the arguments of `export` like assignments as a special case under some conditions).

One problem with that approach is if the value of `$PWD` ends in newline characters (unlikely in practice) as *command substitution* strips **all** trailing newline characters. So in:

```
mkdir $'foo\n\n'
cd $'foo\n\n'
export BWD="$(basename -- "$PWD")"
```

`$BWD` will contain `foo` instead of `$'foo\n\n'`.

Instead, you may want to use shell builtin operators to get that base name. In `zsh`, that can be done with `$PWD:t` (`t` for tail); in all POSIX-like shells (including zsh), that can be done with `${PWD##*/}` which removes everything up to the right-most `/` from the content of `$PWD`.

It will give a different result however if `$PWD` is `/`. In that case, `basename` returns `/` but `${PWD##*/}` or `$PWD:t` expand to the empty string instead. For a directory like `/foo/bar/` (`$PWD` usually doesn't end in `/` though except for `/` itself), `basename` and `$PWD:t` give `bar`, while `${PWD##*/}` give the empty string again.

For a variable that dynamically expands to the basename of `$PWD`, you may use `ksh93` and its *discipline* function:

`ksh93` also has a builtin version of `basename` provided you have `/opt/ast/bin` ahead of `$PATH`. So in ksh93:

```
$ PATH=/opt/ast/bin:$PATH
$ type basename
basename is a shell builtin version of /opt/ast/bin/basename
$ BWD.get() { .sh.value=${ basename -- "$PWD"; }; }
$ cd /var/log
$ echo "$BWD"
log
$ cd /usr/local
$ echo "$BWD"
local
$ export BWD
$ printenv BWD
local
```

Above, we're using a ksh93-specific form of *command substitution*: `${ the-command; }` which is more efficient in that it doesn't create a subshell environment to run the command.

For the `bash` shell, see [Prevent command substitution from running when declaring a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640687) for some approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the construct `foo="$(command)"` to return the output of `command` into the variable `foo`.  So, for your use-case:

```
$ BWD="$(basename "$PWD")"
```

Comment: Or `BWD=${PWD##*/}`

Comment: True, but does not answer the underlying actual question asked (to wit: how to assign the output of a command into a variable).

Comment: eh? What do you think BWD is? The fact that OP assumes it requires a command does not make it necessary, just misguided.

Comment: Again, this specific use-case does in fact not require a command, but the question explicitly asked was "how do I get the output of a command into a variable".

Comment: OP also *explicitly* says: "Specifically, I want an environment variable ($BWD) that is the basename of $PWD" Don't selectively quote just because you assume it supports your argument, that is bad faith. OP wanted an outcome, and like many posters, assumed there was only one route there.

Comment: Funny thing is, I don't even remember which of you is the correct interpretation of the question!