# Prevent command substitution from running when declaring a variable

Tags: bash, variable, command-substitution

So i recently noticed that, when declaring a variable using a command substitution, let's say like so:

```bsh
var=$(echo "this is running" > test; cat test)
```

Then it *will* run (the file `test` will be created) , even though i didn't yet called it (technically), which i would like so:

```bsh
var=$(echo "this is running" > test; cat test)
echo "$var" # is where i would "normally" call the variable
```

How could I prevent the command substitution from actually running when declaring it in a variable, so it only actually *run* when I call the said variable?

PS: Well aware this is kind of a bad example, but it serve well to demonstrate what i mean, although with "useless use of cat" and "useless use of echo"...

Comment: Try using a function instead.

Comment: What other approach (beside using a function) could i use? just curious :) (don't mind using a function but would usually do that only if it's for a decently sized logic/command) @Quasímodo

Comment: Yeah, i did thought of that (thought didn't know this was the normal behavior, which is why i asked initially) @FelixJN

Comment: Similar:  [Output to variable with an indirect command (eval)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/205533)

Comment: What you are dealing with is a string that represents a piece of shell code that you want to run _later_.  This is the typical use for functions.

Comment: Also: [How to implement "generators" like $RANDOM?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/254962)

Comment: Mainly in case where i use said command substitution more than once AND in cases where said command substitution is too long to be repeated/typed more than once (in which case, i guess the logical thing would be a function...) @Quasímodo

Comment: @NordineLotfi I think you are just mistaken: A (bash) variable is always a string. There is no `var=$something` that would dynamically return the current value of `$something` - `$var` will be set to the current value of `$something` and that's it. Anything dynamic must be achieved otherwise (e.g. function).

Comment: See also: [What shells support "value substitution" like MirBSD Korn Shell?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/611364)

Comment: @FelixJN, bash variables can be string or array or associative array or namerefs. There are special variables like `$SECONDS`, `$RANDOM`, `$PWD`... whose contents is automatically generated. You can also set the `integer` attribute on a variable which causes its contents to be interpreted as arithmetic expression (though in the case of `bash`, that's done upon assignment only *after* the attribute has been set; still, see `a='b[$(uname>&2)]' bash -c 'var=$a; typeset -i var; var=var+1'` for instance).

Comment: Your wording seems strange to me.  You use the word 'call' with a variable, but you don't call a variable, you call a function.  You assign a value to the variable in the first line which runs the code and you use the value assigned to that variable later.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware i may not use the right word for the right term, but at least (seeing the other answer/replies) i can see my thought/right meaning were conveyed, so no harm done i believe :) @JasonGoemaat I appreciate that you corrected me though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sound like you want a variable whose contents is dynamically generated.

`bash` does not have support for [ksh93's *disciplines*, or zsh's *dynamic named directory* or mksh's *value substitution*](/a/611364) which would make it easier, but you could use this kind of hack, using namerefs:

```
var_generator() { date --iso-8601=ns; }
var_history=()
typeset -n var='var_history[
  ${##${var_history[${#var_history[@]}]=$(var_generator)}},${#var_history[@]}-1
]'
```

Here with `var` defined as a reference to an element of the `$var_history` array, using the fact that array indices are evaluated dynamically and allow running arbitrary code (here used to run the `var_generator` function and assign its output to a new element of the array).

Then:

```
bash-5.1$ echo "$var"
2021-03-23T13:36:43,243211696+00:00
bash-5.1$ echo "$var"
2021-03-23T13:36:45,517726619+00:00
```

That sounds a bit too convoluted though where you could just use `$(var_generator)` here. One advantage though is that you can still do things like `${var#pattern}` while `bash` (contrary to `zsh`) won't let you do `${$(cmd)#pattern}`.

Comment: In your example, can i just replace the `var_generator` by the actual command, or I'm i obliged to put the command i want to use in a command substitution inside a function? (like you did with `var_generator`)

Comment: @NordineLotfi, yes, you can put the command directly in there without using an intermediary function. Beware of quoting though.

Comment: Is there a version of this trick for zsh, too?

Answer (score 1):

It runs because you did call it. Shell expansions happen right there, unlike e.g. variables in Make, which usually are lazily evaluated. If you did `var='$(...)'`, the command substitution wouldn't run, but it would be difficult to run it later, either. This is similar to how something `foo=$bar` copies the value of `bar` at that moment, instead of looking at it later when `foo` is eventually used.

The simple alternative is to use a function instead. E.g. this should print two dates that are around 5 seconds apart:

```
getdate() {
    date +"%F %T"
}
a=$(getdate)
sleep 5
b=$(getdate)
echo "$a $b"
```

The downside of using a function is that the string operations you can use  with parameter expansion aren't available. You can't do `${(getdate)% *}` to get just the first part of the output, you'll have to do `foo=$(getdate); foo=${foo% *};`